# How to make ragg::agg_png device work with ggsave?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ragg

When I try to use the new-ish [`ragg::agg_png()`](http://ragg.r-lib.org/reference/agg_png.html) device with [`ggplot2::ggsave()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html), the image does not appear to save correctly.

Take the following reprex. I make a simple plot and then save it using the `agg_png()` function directly, and with `ggsave()`. The image saved with the `agg_png()` device directly comes out as expected. However, when I use `ggsave()`, it's almost like the units are being ignored. You can't tell, but there is a *tiny* image beneath the final code output. In that output, we can see that the image is only 7x7 px, even though inches have been specified by the units. From [this blog post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/modern-text-features/#using-ragg), it doesn't seem like anything extra should be required to make `ggsave()` work beyond setting `device = agg_png`.

Are there additional parameters I need to specify? Including session info in case there is something system-specific going on.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
library(ragg)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point()

# save plot --------------------------------------------------------------------
agg_png(filename = "agg_png.png", width = 7, height = 7, units = "in",
        res = 320)
print(p)
dev.off()

ggsave("agg_png-ggsave.png", plot = p, device = agg_png, width = 7, height = 7,
       units = "in", dpi = 320)

# look at images ---------------------------------------------------------------
dev <- image_read("agg_png.png")
print(dev)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   format width height colorspace matte filesize density
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
#> 1 PNG     2240   2240 sRGB       FALSE    55978 126x126
```

[image]

```r
ggs <- image_read("agg_png-ggsave.png")
print(ggs)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   format width height colorspace matte filesize density
#>   <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>  
#> 1 PNG        7      7 sRGB       FALSE      116 28x28
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 10.16         
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Chicago             
#>  date     2021-03-01                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version    date       lib source                            
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  backports     1.2.1      2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  cli           2.3.1      2021-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                    
#>  colorspace    2.0-0      2020-11-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  crayon        1.4.1      2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  curl          4.3        2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)                    
#>  DBI           1.1.1      2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  debugme       1.1.0      2017-10-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  digest        0.6.27     2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  dplyr         1.0.4      2021-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.1)                    
#>  fansi         0.4.2      2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  farver        2.1.0      2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                    
#>  fs            1.5.0      2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  generics      0.1.0      2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.3.9000 2021-03-01 [1] Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@dbd7d79)
#>  glue          1.4.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  highr         0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  htmltools     0.5.1.1    2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  httr          1.4.2      2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  knitr         1.31.5     2021-02-24 [1] Github (yihui/knitr@ca09938)      
#>  labeling      0.4.2      2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  lifecycle     1.0.0      2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  magick      * 2.6.0      2021-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  magrittr      2.0.1      2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  mime          0.10       2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  pillar        1.5.0      2021-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                    
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  png           0.1-7      2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  purrr         0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  R6            2.5.0      2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  ragg        * 1.1.0.9000 2021-03-01 [1] Github (r-lib/ragg@05bd5a7)       
#>  Rcpp          1.0.6      2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  reprex        1.0.0      2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  rlang         0.4.10     2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  rmarkdown     2.7.2      2021-03-01 [1] Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@c0b8584)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  scales        1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  stringi       1.5.3      2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  stringr       1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  styler        1.3.2      2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  systemfonts   1.0.1      2021-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  textshaping   0.3.1      2021-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                    
#>  tibble        3.1.0      2021-02-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  utf8          1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  vctrs         0.3.6      2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  withr         2.4.1      2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  xfun          0.21       2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  xml2          1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#>  yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default units for `ragg` device is in `px`.  Change it to inches and try this

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point()

png <- function(...) ragg::agg_png(..., res = 300, units = "in")
ggsave("agg_png-ggsave.png", plot = p, device = png, width = 3, height = 3, units = "in",
       dpi = 100) # units = "in"

ggs <- image_read("agg_png-ggsave.png")
print(ggs)
```

Actually, you can just try this

```
ggsave("agg_png-ggsave.png", p, device = ragg::agg_png, res = 300,  units = "in") 
ggs <- image_read("agg_png-ggsave.png")
print(ggs)
```

Comment: Thanks @YBS. In the ggsave() call in the question, units is specified as "in". Is there a way to make ggsave acknowledge this without overwriting the png function?

Comment: Please see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4347) for more info.